# Как менять кастомные темы в настройках Android приложений

Tags: java, android, android-themes, android-ui

Делаю свое первое приложение на Android. Хотелось бы реализовать функционал настроек (смена стиля). Стили сделал, реализовал спиннер, установил ArrayAdapter. Вот что есть:

```
package com.churkin.myprojectfirst;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner spinnercolor;
SharedPreferences colorPref;
final String COLOR_PREF = "COLOR_PREF";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    setTheme(R.style.FireBrickTheme);
    setTitle("Настройки");
    spinnercolor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercolor);
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnersettings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnercolor.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnercolor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnersettings);
            String item = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            setColor(item);
            if(!item.equals("Стандарт")){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Установлена тема: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();}
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
private void setColor (String color){

switch(color){
    case "Стандарт":
        pref(color);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        break;
    case "DodgerBlue":
        pref(color);
        setTheme(R.style.DodgerBlueTheme);
        break;
    case "ForestGreen":
        pref(color);
        setTheme(R.style.ForestGreenTheme);
        break;
    case "FireBrick":
        pref(color);
        setTheme(R.style.FireBrickTheme);
        break;
    case "DarkOrange":
        pref(color);
        setTheme(R.style.DarkOrangeTheme);
        break;   }
}
private void pref(String color){
    colorPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = colorPref.edit();
    ed.putString(COLOR_PREF, color);
    ed.apply();
}
```

Как нужно сделать, чтобы при выборе какого-либо пункта Spinner тема менялась на соответствующий цвет в других Activity, а также в текущем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно много разных способов придумать, например, можно сделать так:

1. Создаем класс `ThemeUtils`.  Так как мы динамически меняем тему из *spinner'a* мы должны сделать это программно. Это делается путем вызова метода `setTheme()` в методе активности `onCreate()`, перед любым вызовом `setContentView()`. Чтобы изменить тему, вам нужно просто перезагрузить *activity*.

   ```
   public class ThemeUtils{
   private static int sTheme;

   public final static int FIRE_BRICK = 0;
   public final static int DODGER_BLUE = 1;

   public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
       sTheme = theme;
       activity.finish();
       activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
       activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,
               android.R.anim.fade_out);
       }

   public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
       switch (sTheme) {
       default:
           activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
           break;
       case FIRE_BRICK:
           activity.setTheme(R.style.FireBrickTheme);
           break;
       case DODGER_BLUE:
           activity.setTheme(R.style.DodgerBlueTheme);
           break;
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Далее можно оформить выбор темы в отдельном activity, ну или вставите код в свое, просто как пример использования.

   ```
   public class ThemeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private Spinner spThemes;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Обязательно делаем вызов метода по установке темы до setContentView
       ThemeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
       // и только после установки делаем сам setContentView
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_theme);
       setupSpinnerItemSelection();
   }

   private void setupSpinnerItemSelection() {
       spThemes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercolor);
       spThemes.setSelection(ThemeApplication.currentPosition);

       spThemes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                   int position, long id) {
               if (ThemeApplication.currentPosition != position) {
                   ThemeUtils.changeToTheme(ThemeActivity.this, position);
               }
               ThemeApplication.currentPosition = position;
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });

   }
   }
   ```
3. Чтобы запомнить какая у нас тема сейчас установлена, создадим параметр на уровне Application:

   ```
   public class ThemeApplication extends Application {
         // Храним текущее положение спинера
         public static int currentPosition;
   }
   ```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, немного разобрался :) Пойду пробовать все это )

Comment: @АлександрЧуркин как попробуете, напишите фитбэк =)